# ¿Ordenar lista de comentario en moongoose descendente?

Tags: nodejs, angular, api, mongoose

Hola buenas tarde tengo un problemas quería ordenar los comentarios que se realicen de tal manera que se vea el primero el mas nuevo de una manera descendente de manera que donde pone quiero ser el primero que sea el primero y e numero 1 el ultimo
[image: e]
estoy utilizando moongose en la consulta de esta manera pero no funciona , según en la documentación utiliza el `find` pero yo estoy usando el `findById`  tengo varias preguntas ha realizar.

- ¿Se puede hacer la consulta de esta manera como muestra el código ?
- ¿O es que solo funciona en el método `find` y no en el `findById`?

el fragmento del codigo es este api es este

```js
 Topic.findById(topic._id)
      .populate('user')
      .populate({path:'comments.user',sort:{'date':-1}})
      .exec((err, topic)=>{
        if(err){
            return res.status(500).send({
            status: 'error',
            message:'Erro en la petición ',
          });
        }
        if(!topic){
            return res.status(404).send({
            status: 'error',
            message:'No exite el tema',
           });
        }
                              
        //devolver el resultado 
        return res.status(200).send({
        status: 'success',
        topic: topic
        }); 
  });
```

utilizo la version de moongose:

> "mongoose": "^5.9.23",

el json de la base de dato de prueba es esta y quería ordenar los comments de forma descente

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f0aea697628400352e07c10"),
    "date" : ISODate("2020-07-12T10:48:09.127Z"),
    "comments" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5f0c80f94851c105944cb054"),
            "user" : ObjectId("5f0062b83eda7d0a889761ff"),
            "content" : "1",
            "date" : ISODate("2020-07-13T15:42:49.303Z")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5f0c80fa4851c105944cb055"),
            "user" : ObjectId("5f0062b83eda7d0a889761ff"),
            "content" : "2",
            "date" : ISODate("2020-07-13T15:42:50.897Z")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5f0c81034851c105944cb056"),
            "user" : ObjectId("5f0062b83eda7d0a889761ff"),
            "content" : "3\n",
            "date" : ISODate("2020-07-13T15:42:59.507Z")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5f0c840e9c0fde05f60ff39b"),
            "user" : ObjectId("5f0062b83eda7d0a889761ff"),
            "content" : "sdfsdf",
            "date" : ISODate("2020-07-13T15:55:58.072Z")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5f0c847b4526ae05fd58870f"),
            "user" : ObjectId("5f0062b83eda7d0a889761ff"),
            "content" : "asda",
            "date" : ISODate("2020-07-13T15:57:47.862Z")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5f0c84874526ae05fd588710"),
            "user" : ObjectId("5f0062b83eda7d0a889761ff"),
            "content" : "asdas",
            "date" : ISODate("2020-07-13T15:57:59.637Z")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5f0c84924526ae05fd588711"),
            "user" : ObjectId("5f0062b83eda7d0a889761ff"),
            "content" : "quiero que sea el primero \n",
            "date" : ISODate("2020-07-13T15:58:10.526Z")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5f0c84cb1bbb6706054f5323"),
            "user" : ObjectId("5f0062b83eda7d0a889761ff"),
            "content" : "sdfsd",
            "date" : ISODate("2020-07-13T15:59:07.116Z")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5f0c84dd9930b6060bb3c4d7"),
            "user" : ObjectId("5f0062b83eda7d0a889761ff"),
            "content" : "AS",
            "date" : ISODate("2020-07-13T15:59:25.510Z")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5f0c896b39f3dd0677620570"),
            "user" : ObjectId("5f0062b83eda7d0a889761ff"),
            "content" : "asdas",
            "date" : ISODate("2020-07-13T16:18:51.269Z")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5f0c897339f3dd0677620571"),
            "user" : ObjectId("5f0062b83eda7d0a889761ff"),
            "content" : "aaaaa",
            "date" : ISODate("2020-07-13T16:18:59.488Z")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5f0c899dbe0e13067de422df"),
            "user" : ObjectId("5f0062b83eda7d0a889761ff"),
            "content" : "sdfsdf",
            "date" : ISODate("2020-07-13T16:19:41.354Z")
        }
    ],
    "title" : "JAVASCRIPT ",
    "content" : "que es mejor php o js",
    "code" : "var  num = 1 \nif(num <=1){\nconsole.log(num)\n}",
    "lang" : "javascript",
    "user" : ObjectId("5f0062b83eda7d0a889761ff"),
    "__v" : 170
}
```

Todas las sugerencias sea bienvenida.
también quería decir que he ordenar por el _id.
y sigues sin funcionar no me lo ordena pero funciona correctamente no rompe me deja poner los comentarios  en la parte frontend estoy utilizando angular.
otra cosas que se me ha ocurrido se podrá ordenar desde el frontend? .

Agradeceria ayuda y sugerencias  gracias .

Estoy intentado hacer un codigo de un comentario mas abajo para editar este comentario pero no me sale

```
Topic.updateOne({_id: topicId}, {$push: {
                            comments: {
                                $each: [comments],
                                $sort: { date: -1 }
                            }
                    
                        }})
                        .exec((err, topic)=>{
                            if(err){
                                return res.status(500).send({
                                    status: 'error',
                                    message:`Erro en la petición ${err}`
                                });
                            }
                            if(!topic){
                                return res.status(404).send({
                                    status: 'error',
                                    message:'No exite el tema',
                                });
                            }
                          
                         //devolverl el resultado 
                            return res.status(200).send({
                                status: 'success',
                                topic
                            }); 
                    });
               });
```

**

### Edicion

**
La funcion completa es :

```js
 add :function(req, res ){
        //Recoger el id del topi de la url 
        var topicId  = req.params.topicId;
        
        //find por id del topic
        Topic.findById(topicId).exec((err, topic )=>{
            if(err){   
                return res.status(500).send({
                    status: 'error',
                    message: 'Error en la peticion',
                    
                   
                });
            }
            if(!topic){   
                return res.status(404).send({
                    status: 'error',
                    message: 'No existe el tema '
                });
            }
            //comprobar objeto usuario y validar datos
            if(req.body.content){
                //validar los datos 
                try{

                    var validate_content= !validator.isEmpty(req.body.content);
               
                }catch(err){
                    return res.status(200).send({
                        message :'No has comentado nada'
                    }); 
                }
                if(validate_content){
                    var comment = { 
                        //user:req.body.,     
                        user:req.user.sub,
                        content : req.body.content

                    };
                    //en la propiedad comen del objeto resultado hacer un push
                    topic.comments.push(comment);
                   
                    //Guardar el topic completo 
                    
                    topic.save((err)=>{
                        if(err){   
                            return res.status(500).send({
                                status: 'error',
                                message: 'Error al guardar el comentario ',
                            });
                        }
                     Topic.findById(topic._id)
                       .populate('user')
                       .populate({path:'comments', populate: {path: 'user'}, options:{sort:{'date':-1}}})
                       .exec((err, topic)=>{
                                if(err){
                                    return res.status(500).send({
                                        status: 'error',
                                        message:`Erro en la petición ${err}`
                                    });
                                }
                                if(!topic){
                                    return res.status(404).send({
                                        status: 'error',
                                        message:'No exite el tema',
                                    });
                                }
                              
                             //devolverl el resultado 
                                return res.status(200).send({
                                    status: 'success',
                                    topic: topic
                                }); 
                        });
                   });
                
                }else{
                    return res.status(200).send({
                        message :'No se han validado los datos del comentario '
                    }); 
                }
            }
           
        });
     
 },
```

Comment: El método `findById()` devuelve un documento, en cambio `find()` devuelve una lista con documentos. Esa es una gran diferencia. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras Perfecto ya lo puedo entender algo mejor. Pero es que cuando utiliza el métod populate (). para ordenarlo los comentarios  lo he utilizado como decia la documentación  des la manera que he puesto yo  el path y las opctiones y no me deja ordenar

Answer (score 1):

La manera correcta sería, a mi parecer, insertando los elementos en el array de manera ordenada. Pero tranquilo que Mongo ya lo hace por nosotros [link a la documentacion](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/).

El `$sort` del populate no te sirve en este caso para ordenar el array sino que lo hace en caso de que estés "populando" una key que tiene un array. (por ejemplo si para comments el campo user fuera un array de users)

Por lo tanto, siguiendo con lo que te mencionaba al principio, te sugiero que la consulta del `findById` no hagas ningún sort y para agregar los comments al array utilices lo siguiente:

```
Topic.updateOne({_id: idTopic}, {$push: {
    comments: {
        $each: [newComment],
        $sort: { date: -1 }
    }
}})
```

Comment: Voy mira mañana con más tranquilidad  en el update pero yo estoy usando  findoneandupdate . ¿No se si esto funcionaría @Lean Szikora

Comment: Em no llego a entender bien a lo que te referís. Pero si la pregunta es si funciona lo que te recomendé con `findOneAndUpdate`, la respuesta es sí.

Comment: hola buenos dias el método que ha puesto era para actualizar el comentario es asi ?

Comment: Te entendi! Nono en este caso es para crear un nuevo comentario por eso hacemos un `$push`. Lo que se está actualizando es el Topic

Comment: Hola buenas tarde he intentado hace el codigo que me dice pero me dice un fallo en el backend algo como este  CastError: Cast to embedded failed for value "3" at path "comments". Se me corta la ejecucion y me da fallo. Gracia por tu paciencia @LeanSzikora

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEMA**

El problema está en la forma que pasas la opción `sort` al método `populate`. Actualmente lo tienes así:

```
Topic.findById(topic._id)
  .populate('user')
  .populate({path:'comments.user', sort:{'date':-1}}) // <- aqui está el problema
  //...
```

Lo cual es incorrecto.

**SOLUCIÓN**

De acuerdo a la [documentación](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.populate), las diferentes opciones (`sort`, `limit`, etc.) al momento de realizar un proceso de `populate`, debes pasarlas dentro de un objeto de opciones identificado con el nombre `options`:

```
Topic.findById(topic._id)
  .populate('user')
  .populate({path:'comments.user', options: {sort: {'date':-1}}})
  //...
```

Realizando una replica aproximada de tus datos, el resultado obtenido es el esperado:

```js
{
  comments: [
    {
      _id: 5f0dec373f2e604b13a1f522,
      user: 5f0062b83eda7d0a889761ff,
      content: 'sdfsdf',
      date: 2020-07-13T16:19:41.354Z,
      __v: 0
    },
    //...
    {
      _id: 5f0dec373f2e604b13a1f517,
      user: 5f0062b83eda7d0a889761ff,
      content: '1',
      date: 2020-07-13T15:42:49.303Z,
      __v: 0
    }
  ],
  _id: 5f0dda27c9df7a5d5aec6aa0,
  date: 2020-07-12T10:48:09.127Z,
  title: 'JAVASCRIPT ',
  content: 'que es mejor php o js',
  code: 'var  num = 1 \nif(num <=1){\nconsole.log(num)\n}',
  lang: 'javascript',
  user: 5f0062b83eda7d0a889761ff
}
```

Podemos observar que el primer elemento del Array de `comments` es el más reciente (en cuanto a orden por fecha) y el último es el más antiguo.

**EDICIÓN**

En tu [comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/373166/ordenar-lista-de-comentario-en-moongoose-descendente/373510#comment670225_373510) indicas que recibes un error, que lastimosamente me pasé por alto.

Cuando tienes una lista de documentos y deseas poblar (*populate*) un campo de cada documento de la lista, debes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
Topic.findById(topic._id)
  .populate('user')
  .populate({path:'comments', populate: {path: 'user'}, options:{sort:{'date':-1}}}) 
  //...
```

Como puedes observar, se usa un valor `populate` dentro del método `populate`. Este valor indica el campo del elemento del Array que deseamos poblar. En tu caso, deseas poblar la lista de comentarios, y de cada comentario deseas poblar el campo `user`. Esta es la forma de realizar dicho proceso. Mayor información en la [documentación](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate_multiple_documents).

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Comment: le he puesto como lo tiene se me corta la ejecución y me devuelve el error este (MongooseError: Cannot populate with `sort` on path comments.user because it is a subproperty of a document array) gracias